# in app purchase, SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased retries

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase

I'm implementing In App Purchase and am validating receipts on my server.

When I encounter `SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased` during `paymentQueue:updatedTransactions:` I send the receipt to my server for validation.  When my server responds with an OK I call `finishTransaction`.

If my server is offline or I'm otherwise unable to validate the receipt, what triggers the app to call `paymentQueue:updatedTransactions:` again, effectively giving me a chance to retry the validation?  I've noted that restarting the app does this - is there anything else?  Will it get called again on some fixed frequency while the app remains running?

Is there a manual way to force the transaction-queue to cycle?

Answer (score 1):

I think TomSwift doesn't want to restore purchased payment,
but he want application to call 
paymentQueue:updatedTransactions 
with SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased flag again
of non finishTransaction

and only way he know is re-launch the app

I used to try 
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] removeTransactionObserver:mMyStoreObserver];
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:mMyStoreObserver];
again

but it doesn't work..

the problem of non finishTransaction is 
apple will said it have been purchased but never been downloaded
and it will enter SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed when try to purchased same product id again.

Answer (score 0):

You can have the App call a

> [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];

This will send to

> paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray
>   *)transactions

a set of all of the transactions with:

> SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored

rather than

> SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased